# Flipping and rotation an image with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, rotating, reflection

I have the following issue.
I would like to emulate the friezes of this webpage.
\url{https://maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/4/vol1/architecture/Math/seven.html}

I'm stuck at F6 and F7 images.

For F6 I have tried the following code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={footprints, foot length=40pt, foot of=gnome}]
\foreach \x in {1,3,...,9}
\draw [decorate] (\x,0) -- (\x+1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[xshift=-1 cm, yshift=-1 cm, rotate=180, decoration={footprints, foot length=40pt, foot of=gnome}]
\foreach \x in {1,3,...,9}
\fill [decorate] (\x+1,0) -- (\x,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer below uses the macro `\pgf@lib@foot@of@gnome` from the TikZ library `decorations.footprints`.

A command `\footstep` is defined which takes 4 arguments. The first two arguments determine the `xscale` and `yscale`. The last two arguments determine the position.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.footprints}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\footstep}[4]{
  \begin{scope}[
    shift={(#3*1.2pt,#4*1.2pt)},
    xscale=#1,
    yscale=#2,
    shift={(-0.5pt,-0.5pt)}
  ]
    \pgf@lib@foot@of@gnome
    \pgfusepath{fill}
  \end{scope}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10]
\foreach\x in {1,2,3,4}{
  \footstep{1}{1}{\x}{0}
  \footstep{1}{-1}{\x}{-1}
}
\end{tikzpicture}\\\hline
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10]
\foreach\x in {1,3,5}{
  \footstep{1}{1}{\x}{0}
  \footstep{1}{-1}{\x}{-1}
}
\foreach\x in {2,4,6}{
  \footstep{-1}{1}{\x}{0}
  \footstep{-1}{-1}{\x}{-1}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, @matexmatics